# Show more date times

Tags: php, date, time, format

I found a helpful function for mine site. The thing is it shows only the days, like Monday, Friday or Saturday. But how I can show more stuff like "Monday 20 September" ?

```
$day["Mon"] = "Monday";
$day["Tue"] = "Friday";
$day["Tue"] = "Etc.."; 

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Brussels');
$date = date('l');
$checkTime = '1600';

if( date( 'Hi' ) >= $checkTime) {
$date2 = date(strtotime($date.' +1 Weekday'));
$date3 = date(strtotime($date.' +2 Weekday'));
}
if (date('l') == 'Friday'){
$date2 = date(strtotime($date.' +1 Weekday'));
$date3 = date(strtotime($date.' +3 Weekday'));
}
if (date('l') == 'Saturday'){
$date2 = date(strtotime($date.' +1 Weekday'));
$date3 = date(strtotime($date.' +2 Weekday'));
} 

echo '<p>Between'.$day[date("D", $date2)].'</spanp';
echo '<p>'.$day[date("D", $date3)].'</p>';
```

Something like this would be helpful:

```
echo date("F j, Y, g:i a");
```

Comment: You have the $date2 and $date3 and you can use the date function you mentioned on them

Comment: My question has apparently been downvoted. Well, guys, it means it's a stupid question, but I can't fix this.

Comment: Is there something you didn’t understand of my comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/Brussels' );
$date = date( 'l' );
$checkTime = '1600';

if( date( 'Hi' ) >= $checkTime ) {
  $date2 = date( 'l j F', strtotime( $date . ' +1 Weekday' ) );
  $date3 = date( 'l j F', strtotime( $date . ' +2 Weekday' ) );
}

if ( date( 'l' ) == 'Friday' ){
  $date2 = date( 'l j F', strtotime( $date . ' +1 Weekday' ) );
  $date3 = date( 'l j F', strtotime( $date . ' +3 Weekday' ) );
}

if ( date( 'l' ) == 'Saturday' ){
  $date2 = date( 'l j F', strtotime( $date . ' +1 Weekday' ) );
  $date3 = date( 'l j F', strtotime( $date . ' +2 Weekday' ) );
}

echo '<p>Between: ' . $date2 . '</p>';
echo '<p>And: ' . $date3 . '</p>';
```

Comment: I missed a crucial point, it was the echo print statement which I forgot. I was still using $day[date("D", $date2)]. Your solution is perfect. Thanks for this btw!